# Perl-grep stops matching after 32k characters

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

My perl-grep statement is not capturing all the elements of a large match (~32k characters), but it has no trouble with smaller matches.

The grep command I want to use in order to grab "allowed [ < TEXT > ]":

```
    grep -P '(?si)^\s*allowed\s*\[.*?\]' file.txt
```

For some reason, if the file is large-ish, the dot stops matching lines. Therefore the above grep doesn't match anything because '.*?\]' can't eat enough to find the ']'.

```
    grep -P '(?si)^\s*allowed\s*\[.*' bigFile.txt | wc
1883 1883 32764
```

But it can still consume the entire file using .*:

```
    grep -P '(?si).*' bigFile.txt | wc
10003 10003 178910
```

BigFile.txt:

```
    allowed
    [
        com.bar.baz1
        com.bar.baz2
        ....
        com.bar.baz10000
    ]
```

As you can see, the BigFile should be matched in its entirety. Instead it stops after about 32k characters, about at line 1880.

I am using Grep2.5.1. My best guess is that this version of grep can only match about 2^15=32768 characters from within a pattern...

For comparison, on another machine running grep 2.6.3, the following works fine

```
grep -Pzo '(?si)^\s*allowed\s*\[.*?\]' bigFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a non-greedy operator in one command:

```
grep -P '(?si)^\s*allowed\s*\[.*?\]' file.txt
                               ^^
```

and a greedy operator in the other:

```
grep -P '(?si)^\s*allowed\s*\[.*' bigFile.txt | wc
                               ^
```

This may cause differences in how `grep` matches your file.

Comment: True. But I am trying to show the issue I see. if ".*" won't match all the lines, then ".*?\\]" will never match because it can't eat enough to find the ']'